# How to retrieve the top row in an Azure table

Tags: c#, azure

Do I need to get all the values and than break the foreach block after the first record? Like below:

```
TableQuery<CustomerEntity> query = new TableQuery<CustomerEntity>()
    .Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "Smith"));

// Print the fields for each customer.
foreach (CustomerEntity entity in table.ExecuteQuery(query))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}\t{2}\t{3}", entity.PartitionKey, entity.RowKey,
        entity.Email, entity.PhoneNumber);
    break;
}
```

Or is there a select top command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default sort order for table storage is by partition key and row key.  Are you looking to find the most recently added item?  If so, you could leverage the PK and RK to help you, setting the RK value to something like DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks - DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks.  Then using LINQ's Take() function to return the necessary rows.

Comment: And if you had written the code to do the operation you just described I would have upvoted your answer.